# KeDei LCD version 6.0 with Raspberry Pi 3 driver problem

Tags: pi-3, display, driver

I got KeDei LCD with version 6.0 and inserted this to my raspberry pi 3

When I install drivers or images, after reboot i see on this display, how system load, and then screen become white.

I tried to install drivers for my pi 3 from site http://kedei.net/raspberry/raspberry.html
1. LCD_show_v6_0_2.tar.gz
2. image rpi_35_v6_0_2_jessie_kernel_4_4_11.rar
3. Image rpi_35_v6_jessie8_kernel_4_1_19.rar

Nothing works for me. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Might be a problem with display. I have all the same and after driver installation (6.1.2 version) all works fine. Just a small problem with inverted colors :(

Comment: UPDATE: just installed 6.0.2 version, this fixed colors, screen works fine now.

Comment: display sometime become white when it's badly connected to the pi. Try to check the contact pins.

Comment: I have issue with this display after reboot PI just loading and nothing happen. Can you provide some tuts how to install properly? I follow steps on the website and not get this to work.

Comment: I have just run the installation from the package, nothing special.